# opengl white window - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, opengl

I am opengl beginner.
I set the DLLs, Library, Header but, error occurred.
My development environment is win7 ( 64bit ).

For reference -
DLLs : C:\Windows\System32, C:\Windows\SysWOW64 // glu32.dll, glut.dll, glut32.dll, opengl32.dll

Libs : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib // glut.lib, glut32.lib

Header : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl  // GL.H, GLAUX.H, GLU.H, glut.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/glut.H>

void DoDisplay ( void )
{
    glClearColor ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glBegin ( GL_TRIANGLES );

    glVertex2f ( 0.0, 0.5 );
    glVertex2f ( -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f ( 0.5, -0.5 );

    glEnd ();
    glFlush ();
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    glutInit ( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize ( 300, 300 );
    glutInitWindowPosition ( 0, 0 );
    glutCreateWindow ( "OpenGL" );
    glutDisplayFunc ( DoDisplay );
    glutMainLoop ();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit :

White Window : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GJoN.jpg

This code is simply output the white triangle.

Win32 Project -> Console Project.

Problem not solved.. sorry.

Error is https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GJoN.jpg

Comment: no `glutInit()`, missing `glBegin()` and some other problems, you're going to have to be more specific with what the problem is and what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're using immediate mode. You have a `glEnd()` but no `glBegin()`
- As PeterT also pointed out, you have no call to `glutInit`
- If your paths are specified like the way you have printed, you'll run into a problem. You have both forward and backslashes, which at least in my experience ruins the path.
- You're not clearing the screen to a specific color, nor are you setting your vertices to a specific color. This may be the case of drawing a polar bear in a snow storm.

Check out

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

and

```
glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
```

- As Drew McGowen pointed out, you're not specifying any transformation or projection matrices.
- I would **strongly** recommend looking for a tutorial on OpenGL to get a good explanation of all the things you need to do to draw a triangle and *why*. Lighthouse3d, Swiftless, OGLDev - there are many that should show you the basics.
- One more point: You're trying to learn code that has been deprecated for ~7 years. You should learn the new programmable pipeline instead of the fixed function pipeline because it is faster and gives you more control.

Comment: To add on to this, there's no `GL_MODELVIEW` or `GL_PROJECTION` matrix set, which may cause issues as well (unless GLUT sets up defaults).

Comment: Thx, but my problem is not solved. Excuse me, could you please look my code again?

Answer (score 1):

```
void DoDisplay ( void )
{
    ...
    glFlush ();
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    ...
    glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    ....
}
```

`glFlush()` is insufficient when using `GLUT_DOUBLE`.  Use `glutSwapBuffers()` instead.

Comment: I have same problem, I tried your code and other user's instructions, but fail. So tell me how you did that

Comment: @SachinKumar: Start up a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).